# Как через SqlYog или другой системой управления базой данных , управлять базой которая находится в контейнере?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, navicat

В  Windows 10 начал использовать  docker,  для локальной разработки, нужно иметь доступ к  MariaDb базе которая находится в контейнере через SqlYog  или Navicat как это сделать ?

использую docker-compose.yml.

```
   version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    image: 'laravelapp'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: library/mariadb:10.4.12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "33061:33061"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'currency_api'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secret"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: а что подключение к `localhost:33061` не работает?

Comment: Нет,     [вот конфигурации  для соеденения с базой](https://prnt.sc/10jcps7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот кусочек конфига:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "33061:33061"
```

означает "пробросить порт 33061 хоста на 33061 контейнера". Однако MariaDB по-умолчанию работает на 3306 и если Вы не меняли конфиг БД, то получается что проброс портов ведет на порт, где ничто не слушает.

Нужно поменять порт контейнера в этом месте:

```yaml
    ports:
        # хост:контейнер
      - "33061:3306"
```

После чего БД должна быть доступна для хоста на `localhost:33061`.